# SQL- SELECT minimum by other column

Tags: sql, oracle, min

Let's have a table named `employers` with columns:

```
id
cash
```

and I need to select `id` and `cash` for employers that have minimal cash lower than minimal cash in rows with `id = 2`.

An example of the table:

```
----------
id    cash
----------
1      100
2      200
2      150
2      125
3      320
4      400
```

It should select only the first row, because minimal cash in rows with `id 2` is `125` and only this row has lower cash.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT id, MIN(cash)
FROM employers
WHERE cash < (MIN(cash) 
WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: WHERE cash<SELECT MIN(cash) FROM table WHERE id=2;

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: THis is oracle then not mysql.

Comment: aaah,yes, im sorry, i forget to say that,its really oracle

Comment: You are using Oracle, not MySQL

Comment: If the error is Oracle, then this is Oracle and not MySQL.  I edited the tags appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query

```
SELECT id, cash
FROM employers
WHERE cash < (SELECT MIN(cash) 
              FROM employers
              WHERE id = 2 
              GROUP BY id);
```

**EDIT:** Removed the `MIN` from the query, this should work with your data sample.
Also I suggest that you modify the query based on your requirements.
In case you need only the least cash available at every `employer`, who has less cash than the min cash, then use a `GROUP BY id` and select `MIN(cash)`.

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.ID, min(T1.cash), T2.Id, min(T2.Cash)
FROM Table T1
CROSS JOIN table T2
WHERE T1.CASH < T2.CASH
and T2.ID = 2
and T1.ID <> 2
GROUP BY T1.ID, T2.ID
```